# Android FUNF open sensing framework v0.4 - how to change probe schedule at runtime

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

I would like to be able to start/stop probes dynamically - similar to the FUNF Journal app - and also to alter the configuration of the probes (interval, duration) at runtime. I managed to start/stop the probes, as shown in the [Funf Wifi scanner tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/funf-open-sensing-framework/wiki/WifiScannerTutorial). To change the configuration I tried to hand over a JSON object containing the schedule and type of the probe but the schedule seems to be ignored.

```
JsonObject config = new JsonObject();

        Schedule.BasicSchedule schedule = new BasicSchedule();  
        schedule.setDuration(new BigDecimal(duration));
        schedule.setInterval(new BigDecimal(period));

        JsonObject scheduleJsonObject = mFunfManager.getGson().toJsonTree(schedule).getAsJsonObject();
        scheduleJsonObject.remove(TYPE);

        config.add("@schedule", scheduleJsonObject);
        config.addProperty("@type", "edu.mit.media.funf.probe.builtin.AccelerometerSensorProbe");

        AccelerometerSensorProbe accelerometerProbe = mFunfManager.getGson().fromJson(config, AccelerometerSensorProbe.class);
        accelerometerProbe.registerPassiveListener(MainActivity.this);
```

Thanks for your help!